# QSyntaxHighlighter - text selection overrides style

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qplaintextedit

I'm making a custom code editor with `QPlainTextEdit` and `QSyntaxHighlighter` and I've encountered a glitch. I'd like to preserve syntax highlighting even within a selection. However, **colors of the selection (environment colors) override the colors of the text highlighted by `QSyntaxHighlighter` and html tags.** Other attributes like font family are preserved.

---

**Example:**

No selection:             Selection:
 [image: Unselected]      [image: Selected]
                                   (I'd like ***`Hello`*** to be green and `World!` to be black)

---

I've also tried to set the style sheet to:

```
QPlainTextEdit {
    selection-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    selection-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]
Background color overlays the text and well, text color with `alpha = 0` is not visible. I've done that just to rule out the idea that syntax color persists under `selection-color`. It is in fact overlaid by `selection-background-color`.
**Edit:** No, if I also set `selection-background-color` to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, there's no selection and there's no text in that selection. All I see is the background.

---

Approach of the following snippet which makes whole cursor's line highlighted seems like the way to go, but I would basically end up reimplementing all the selection mechanics...

```
QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;
QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();

QTextEdit::ExtraSelection selection;
selection.format.setBackground(lineHighlightColor_);
selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat::FullWidthSelection, true);
selection.cursor = cursor;
selection.cursor.clearSelection();
extraSelections.append(selection);
setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
```

Is there any simpler solution to this?

Comment: did you ever find a simpler solution?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I've resigned. If I had found a simpler approach (I don't know if `QTextEdit::ExtraSelection` is a viable solution), I would have shared it.

Comment: this is a really annoying limitation of the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem reside here :

https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/e03b64c5b1eeebfbbb94d67eb9a9c1d35eaba0bb/src/widgets/widgets/qplaintextedit.cpp#L1939-L1945

QPlainTextEdit use context palette instead of current selection format.

You could create one class inheritings from QPlainTextEdit and override paintEvent

signature :

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
```

Copy the body of the function from github inside the new class paintEvent function  :

https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/e03b64c5b1eeebfbbb94d67eb9a9c1d35eaba0bb/src/widgets/widgets/qplaintextedit.cpp#L1883-L2013

add this function in your cpp file before paintEvent (PlainTextEdit paintEvent need it) :

https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/e03b64c5b1eeebfbbb94d67eb9a9c1d35eaba0bb/src/widgets/widgets/qplaintextedit.cpp#L1861-L1876

add

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QScrollBar>
```

and replace each occurrence of

```
o.format = range.format;
```

whith

```
o.format = range.cursor.blockCharFormat();
o.format.setBackground(QColor(your selection color with alpha));
```

with that your custom PlainTextEdit check the format linked to the current char instead of your PlainTextEdit palette

(beware (L)GPL licence, I just give an opensource workaround)